# should I use a primary key when I generate it as identity?

Tags: postgresql

I shouldnt use serial so I heard I have to use the identity field.

But when I use the identity field, should I also use it as primary key ? because the field should unique and should has a index.

```
id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: That is the by far **the most common** use,, but it is not required. The question is why guarantee a unique not null column if you do not use it as PK.  After all *unique not null* is the requirement for a PK.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? Did you consider using a different column for the primary key? Or not giving the table a primary key at all?

Comment: Whether to define that column as the primary key or not has nothing to do with whether the sequence is created by using `serial` or for an `identity` column.

Comment: @JeffHumphreys [I cannot reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZMs-JUv3). Did you already have non-unique values in the table when you tried to add the primary key?

Comment: @Bergi Here's the code I used

Comment: @Bergi Here's the code I used<br>DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmplt;
CREATE TABLE tmplt (<br>
    id                          int8                  NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY( INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1 CACHE 1 CYCLE)<br>
);<br>
CREATE TABLE gen_id (LIKE tmplt INCLUDING ALL);<br>
ALTER TABLE gen_id ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);<br>It worked this time, must be I had a same named constraint?  Still learning. I didn't save the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every table should have a primary key. An identity column has little use except as an artificial primary key, if no good natural primary key can be found. So the identity column should almost certainly be a primary key. If you already have another primary key, do away with the identity column.